# R: histogram of large dataframe by unixtime converted to formatted date/time

Tags: r, datetime, formatting, histogram, unix-timestamp

I am new to R. I have a large dataframe with unix timestamps.

It is possible to display a histogram via the `hist` command which displays the unix timestamps as formatted date/time?

This is a snippet of the code I am currently using:

```
   hist(u12$unixtime, plot=TRUE)
```

With the following outcome:

[image]

Of course this not very user-friendly.

## Solved!

```
hist(as.POSIXct(u12$unixtime, origin="1970-01-01"), breaks="days", plot=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
hist(as.POSIXct(u12$unixtime, origin="1970-01-01"), breaks="days", plot=TRUE)
```